# Update all items in array of mongoose subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to update many subdocuments of one document. So if this is the schema:

```
user: {
    addresses: [
        {
            location: String
            isActive: Boolean
            _id: false
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to update all `isActive` fields in the subdocument of `addresses`. So I tried this:

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: userId,
    'user.addresses': { $exists: true, $not: { $size: 0 } }
}, { 'user.addresses.isActive': true }
);
```

But I'm getting an error. How can I update all items in an array using mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) operator to do this. Example:

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    _id: userId,
    'user.addresses': { $exists: true, $not: { $size: 0 } }
  }, 
  { 'user.addresses.$[].isActive': true }
);
```